# Codeigniter mysql can't connect in docker

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, docker, nginx

Codeigniter 3.0 can not connect to local mysql, so please let me know the reason.

Error message is SQLSTATE [HY000] [2002] Connection refused.
My Codeigniter is working on Docker.

Specifically on Docker in mac

- php-fpm 7.1
- MySQL 5.7
- Nginx 2.4

Containers are working.

And that MySQL container can be connected from sequel pro or Mac terminal, only from Codeigniter can connect.

Successful connection code from my Mac terminal

```
mysql -uroot -h 127.0.0.1-P 4306 -ppassword
```

**db_test.php**

```
<?php
  try {

    $pdo = new PDO(
    'mysql:dbname=******;host=127.0.0.1;charset=utf8',
    'root',
    'password',
    [
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
        PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
    ]
   );

} catch (PDOException $e) {

   header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8', true, 500);
   exit($e->getMessage()); 

}
```

**result -- SQLSTATE [HY000] [2002] Connection refused.**

**/config/database.php**

```
}elseif (strpos($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'],'myname') !== false && ENVIRONMENT != "test"){
// MyLocal Setting
$db['default'] = array(
        'dsn'   => '',
        'hostname' => '127.0.0.1',
  'port' => '4306',
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => 'password',
        'database' => '******',
        'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
        'dbprefix' => '',
        'pconnect' => FALSE,
        'db_debug' => TRUE,
        'cache_on' => FALSE,
        'cachedir' => '',
        'char_set' => 'utf8',
        'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
        'swap_pre' => '',
        'encrypt' => FALSE,
        'compress' => FALSE,
        'stricton' => FALSE,
        'failover' => array(),
        'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
 version: '2'
   services:
     memcached:
     image: memcached:1.4

   data:
    image: busybox
    volumes:
      - ./misc/data:/var/lib/mysql

  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: mysql_database
      MYSQL_USER: mysql_user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: mysql_pw
      socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
    ports:
      - "4306:3306"
    volumes_from:
      - data
    volumes:
      - ../application/initial.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/initial.sql
    container_name: mysql
nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    links:
      - web
    container_name: nginx
    environment:
     - CI_ENV=localhost

  web:
    build: ./php-fpm71
#    build: ./php-fpm56    <- if you want to use PHP5.6
    volumes:
      - /Users/alberorana/codeigniter/suke10:/var/www/html/suke10
      - ./php-fpm71/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/php.ini
    links:
      - mysql
    environment:
      DATABASE_HOST: '0.0.0.0'
      DATABASE_NAME: 'suke10'
      DATABASE_USER: 'root'
      DATABASE_PASSWORD: 'password'
    container_name: web
```

**etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf in MySQL container**

```
[mysqld]
pid-file        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
datadir         = /var/lib/mysql
#log-error      = /var/log/mysql/error.log
# By default we only accept connections from localhost
#bind-address   = 127.0.0.1
# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0
```

Comment: As its local in `/config/database.php` change `'port' => '4306',` to `'port' => '3306',` you would only connect on 4306 from outside the bridge, eg your laptop.

Comment: Since db_test.php isn't using the CodeIgniter database library I'm thinking that the problem is not with CodeIgniter.

Comment: Thanks ! I tried port 3306, but the result was the same.

Comment: @YumaUchida You try to connect ```host=127.0.0.1``` from inside the php container? (you need to connect with the name of your mysql container (= mysql) and not with localhost. Because localhost from inside your php container is not the same localhost as localhost on your machine where you can connect to the db. This blog could be useful: https://lvthillo.com/create-simple-php-app-using-postgresql-in-docker-compose/

Comment: @ lvthillo
It was exactly right. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your database connection inside the php container is:

```
 mysql:3306
```

Since you in your compioser file, "link" the phpcontainer to the databaser container, and a link is essentliation addition of a line in your hosts-file, so mysql will point to the ip in the internal docker-network for you.

Answer (score 0):

@ lvthillo
We were able to connect by setting the host setting to the mysql container!

```
'mysql:dbname=******;host=mysql;charset=utf8'
```

Answer (score 0):

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"

services:
  webserver:
    build: 
      context: ./bin/webserver
    container_name: '7.3.x-webserver'
    restart: 'always'
    ports:
      - "${HOST_MACHINE_UNSECURE_HOST_PORT}:80"
      - "${HOST_MACHINE_SECURE_HOST_PORT}:443"
    links: 
      - mysql
    volumes: 
      - ${DOCUMENT_ROOT-./www}:/var/www/html
      - ${PHP_INI-./config/php/php.ini}:/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
      - ${VHOSTS_DIR-./config/vhosts}:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled
      - ${LOG_DIR-./logs/apache2}:/var/log/apache2
  mysql:
    build:
      context: "./bin/${DATABASE}"
    container_name: '5.7-mysql'
    restart: 'always'
    ports:
      - "${HOST_MACHINE_MYSQL_PORT}:3306"
    volumes: 
      - ${MYSQL_DATA_DIR-./data/mysql}:/var/lib/mysql
      - ${MYSQL_LOG_DIR-./logs/mysql}:/var/log/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ${MYSQL_DATABASE}
      MYSQL_USER: ${MYSQL_USER}
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    container_name: 'sc-phpmyadmin'
    links:
      - mysql
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: mysql
      PMA_PORT: 3306
      PMA_USER: ${MYSQL_USER}
      PMA_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_USER: ${MYSQL_USER}
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
    ports:
      - '8080:80'
    volumes: 
      - /sessions
  redis:
    container_name: 'sc-redis'
    image: redis:latest
    ports:
      - "${HOST_MACHINE_REDIS_PORT}:6379"
```

/project/application/config/database.php

```
$active_group = 'default';
$query_builder = TRUE;

$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'mysql',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => 'tiger',
    'database' => 'docker',
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

mysql is the name of service(mysql container) && using the same as my hostname